# Returning several rows from a single query, based on a value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have this table:

```
|Fld | Number|
 1     5
 2     2
```

And I want to make a select that retrieves as many `Fld` as the `Number` field has:

```
|Fld |
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
```

How can I achieve this? I was thinking about making a temporary table and instert data based on the `Number`, but I was wondering if this could be done with a single Select statement.

PS: I'm new to SQL

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a single Select statement with an arbitrary number, but you can do it with a limited range of numbers or with a stored procedure.

Comment: I'm using pl/sql developer 8.0.0.1480

Comment: @Roger: With Oracle I think you can do this by using CONNECT BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an great solution (since you still query your table twice, but maybe you can work from it)

```
    SELECT t1.fld, t1.number
    FROM table t1, (
        SELECT ROWNUM number FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(number) FROM t1)) t2
    WHERE t2.number<=t1.number
```

It generates maximum amount of rows needed and then filters it by each row.

Answer (score 3):

You can join with a numbers table:

```
SELECT Fld
FROM yourtable
JOIN Numbers
ON yourtable.Number <= Numbers.Number
```

A numbers table is just a table with a list of numbers:

```
 Number
 1
 2
 3
 etc...
```

Comment: +1, might be a good time for a CTE instead of creating a table for it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if your RDBMS version supports it (although I rather suspect it does), but here is a recursive version:

```
WITH remaining (fld, times) as (SELECT fld, 1
                                FROM <table>
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT a.fld, a.times + 1
                                FROM remaining as a
                                JOIN <table> as b
                                ON b.fld = a.fld
                                AND b.number > a.times)

SELECT fld
FROM remaining
ORDER BY fld
```

Given your source data table, it outputs this (count included for verification):

```
fld    times
=============
1      1 
1      2 
1      3 
1      4 
1      5 
2      1 
2      2
```

Comment: @Roger - For certain types of analytics in SQL, recursive queries are king.  Learn them.  They can be used to do all sorts of fun things.